# How to set jQuery UI dialog defaults

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How do I set the default values for the jQuery UI dialog?
For example, this is how I set the defaults in the jQuery UI datepicker:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

I couldn't find the same functionality in the [dialog
documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found a solution

```
$.extend($.ui.dialog.prototype.options, { modal: true, width: 650 });
```

Comment: `$.extend` mutates the first argument. You'll end up stacking properties into the `options` object. See the mention of using an empty hash in @Groovetrain's answer.

Comment: This is a good solution if you wish to change the default options, which is what the original question asks for.

Answer (score 8):

There's no built-in functionality for that AFAIK, but what I usually do is set them myself in a separate hash like this:

```
var dialog_defaults = {
  autoopen: false,
  buttons: {
    close: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }
  }
};
```

Then when I create the dialog, I use jQuery's extend method to make them work, like this:

```
$('#divvie').dialog(
  $.extend({}, dialog_defaults, {
    autoopen: true
  })
);
```

The second set of arguments you pass in will overwrite/merge with whatever's in the dialog_defaults variable.  Just make sure you put the empty hash (`{}`) in there, or your defaults will get overwritten, that's bitten me in the past.