# jQuery UI Dialog - set a default config

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have several jQuery UI Dialogs handlers, all of which contain the following:

```
open: function(event, ui) {
      $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").removeClass("ui-corner-all");
      $(".ui-dialog").removeClass("ui-corner-all");
},
```

This is so that the dialog has square corners, rather than round ones. I was wondering if it's possible to have this set as default, so that I don't have to insert this code into every dialog config on the page.

I know I can edit the CSS, but it makes more sense to actually remove the class if it's not needed.

Comment: What do you mean by 'set as default'? That would be editing the CSS. I see no need to employ JavaScript every time the dialog is opened when you can easily edit the CSS to remove the rounded corners.

Comment: Might want to see this for a better answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287045/override-jqueryui-dialog-default-options

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know it's not perfect, but you could define your own `defaults` object that contains your defaults. Then if you need to override or add to those defaults, you could use `$.extend`:

```
var dialogDefaults = {
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").removeClass("ui-corner-all");
        $(".ui-dialog").removeClass("ui-corner-all");
    }
};
// then later on:
$("#foo").dialog($.extend({ }, dialogDefaults, {
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 500,
    /* etc... */
}));
```

Also remember that for the events, you can bind to them outside of the options object by using `on` (or its siblings `delegate`, `bind`, and `live`). You can apply that event handler to multiple dialogs by applying the same class to all of your dialogs, for example:

```
$("div.my-dialog-class").on("dialogopen", function (event, ui) {
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").removeClass("ui-corner-all");
    $(".ui-dialog").removeClass("ui-corner-all");
});
```

Just keep in mind that this event handler won't fire off for new dialogs. You could let the event bubble up the DOM to the `body` and attach the event handler there (this is the route I would go):

```
$(document.body).on("dialogopen", "div.my-dialog-class", function (event, ui) {
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").removeClass("ui-corner-all");
    $(".ui-dialog").removeClass("ui-corner-all");
});
```

With this method of event delegation, you are applying your `open` function to all dialogs that will ever be appended to `document.body`.

Comment: What would be the syntax for using this default concept for various dialog property settings (did I say that right) as well? I've got a series of dialogs that all share about 10-12 common property settings and maintenance is becoming a chore. It'd be nice to only have to worry about the unique settings per dialog.

Comment: OK, got it. Spoke too soon. I just added them as normal, before your open: call. I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409633/how-to-set-jquery-ui-dialog-defaults) as a reference. Works great, thanks.